# Magento 1.9.x Product attribute value in both _varchar and _text tables

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Wow this is a strange one.

I have two product attributes which , in the admin, seems to load from the **catalog_product_entity_text** table

```
# value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
'86950', '4', '329', '0', '2887', 'HRC: 20,3–68; HRB: 41–100; HRA: 61-85,6; HV: 80–1599; HB: 76–618; Tensile strength: 255–2180 N/mm2'
```

but save to the **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table.

```
# value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
'116583', '4', '329', '0', '2887', 'HRC: 20,3–68; HRB: 41–100; HRA: 61-85,6; HV: 80–1599; HB: 76–618; Tensile strength: 255–2180 N/mm2 test2'
```

How? Why? What?!  In the attribute admin the frontend_input field is set to "text" / Text Field.  If I change the store_id in the varchar table to 1 (the only store) then, for a moment the value in that table will load into the admin. Saving will reset it to store 0 and then the value in the text table will load from then on again.

Any idea why this might have happened and how to get out of it?

Thanks

UPDATE
The values for backend_type   and frontend_input  inside  the eav_attribute table are different!  But then so are many others

UPDATE 2
OK have made things work.  BY changing the backend_type from varchar to text things seem to be working correctly.